# correlation based disparity map on opencv result is not satisfying enough

Tags: opencv, disparity-mapping

I have used **Normalized Cross Correlation** equation to find **disparity between two rectified images of tsukaba.**

[image: 1]

I searched in horizontal direction in range x=-15:1:15 and in vertical direction in range y=-1:1:1  using a rectangular windows sized 9x9.

then for the `(x,y)` that maximized correlation, disparity for that `(i,j)` was calculated as : `disparity(i,j)=sqrt( x^2 +y^2 )`.

this is the disparity image i get:

[image: My Result]

Which is not as satisfying as the ground truth disparity map:

[image: Ground truth]

is there any post processing that i have to perform to enhance the result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you solved this ?

Comment: I was unable to get any better result using Correlation method. But SGBM Method gave satisfying result. @Raziel